# AWS Managed Apache Airflow: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

We have several different DAGs that we run on Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA). Everything runs fine for about two weeks, then we get this error `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`. No DAGs run once we see this error and we have to restart the MWAA environment to get things working again. Presumably this restart clears out all local files. We do use Kubernetes/EKS for some jobs.

Here are my questions

1. How can I figure out what is filling up the disk space? For some jobs we write files to `/tmp`, but I thought that was ephemeral storage and eventually deleted
2. How can I clear the local files from the MWAA environment without having to restart periodically?

Answer (score 0):

would suggest you use the `tempfile` library and create a temp directory

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
        os.chdir(tmp_dir)
```

At the end of the program, for example, Python will clean up the directory if it wasn't removed, e.g. by the context manager or the cleanup() method.

The /tmp folder might be filling up over time and causing no space issues.